# Javascript Create Div

Tags: javascript, css, html, createelement

I am trying to create a page that creates 5 random DIVS using javascript. For some reason it only works when I have any content before the `<!doctype html>` tag on my page which makes no sense to me. Any insight as to what I am doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>



<div id = "boxHouse">

</div>

<script>
var divNum = 1;
for (x = 0; x<5; x++){

var boxDiv = document.getElementById("boxHouse");

var newElm = document.createElement("div");
newElm.id = divNum;
newElm.style.width = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+2);
newElm.style.height = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+2);
newElm.style.border = "thin solid black";
newElm.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";

 divNum++

 boxDiv.appendChild(newElm);
  }


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'any content before the tag' ?

Comment: Sorry, it got lost, it only displays the divs correclty if I add any character before the doctype tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work if you add units to the width and height:

```
newElm.style.width = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+2) + "px";
newElm.style.height = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+2) + "px";
```

The reason this is needed is a css size without a unit is discarded, so the divs are empty and thus you can only see their borders stacked as a thin black bar at the top of the page.

EDIT: the reason it works if you add something before the doctype is that then the browser goes into quirks mode (as opposed to standards-compliant mode with the doctype) where it is a lot more accepting of non-standard things like broken css units.

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what was wrong with it. Thank you so much. I will never make that mistake again

Comment: I just saw your edit on the post and added some more details to this too. Adding stuff before the doctype makes the doctype not count; it turns off standards mode and the browser is more accepting of non-standard code quirks.